# Swift function with generic argument type

Tags: swift, generics, types

I'm looking for an easy and convenient way to implement a function that accepts all types that can be casted to strings e.g.: `myFunc("This string")` or `myFunc(2)` or `myFunc(true)`. I thought this must be possible with generic parameters and tried something like this:

```
func myFunc<T: StringLiteralConvertible>(param: T? = nil) -> String {
   // ...
   return "\(param)"
}
```

but I had no success so far.

Comment: What is the output for your tests?

Comment: The problem is that the method does not accept Int and Bool as parameter

Comment: You want to return string for Int and Bool parameter? Like muFunc(2) will be "Two" and myFunc(true) will be "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CustomStringConvertible`, not `StringLiteralConvertible`:

```
func myFunc<T: CustomStringConvertible>(param: T? = nil) -> String {
    // ...
    return "\(param)"
}

myFunc("Grimxn") // Optional("Grimxn")
myFunc(12) // Optional(12)
myFunc(true) // Optional(true)
myFunc(-1.234) // Optional(-1.234)
//myFunc() // doesn't work. Compiler can't infer T
```

These will give `Optionals` because you are casting them to `T?` to allow your `nil` default. Drop the default (it doesn't work anyway - `nil` can't imply `T`) to get rid of the `Optional`.

```
func myFunc<T: CustomStringConvertible>(param: T) -> String {
    // ...
    return "\(param)"
}

myFunc("Grimxn") // "Grimxn"
myFunc(12) // "12"
myFunc(true) // "true"
myFunc(-1.234) // "-1.234"
//myFunc((1,2)) // doesn't compile
myFunc(NSDate()) // "2015-10-26 10:44:49 +0000"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but doesn't this make the type-safety useless because the documentation says that `CustomStringConvertible`: "will work for an instance of any type, returning its description if the instance happens to be CustomStringConvertible."

Comment: ... So basically everything that inherits from `NSObject` can be passed.

Comment: It is safe because any type which conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` can be passed otherwise the code won't compile.